# how do you pop up the Save Image/Open in New Page/Copy menu on command in mobile safari?

Tags: iphone, safari, webkit

I need to find out how to make the menu that appears in mobile safari on the iphone/touch when you tap & hold an element appear on a single tap without having to hold. how would i do this? preferably i would use webkit & no js.

Answer (score 0):

UIWebView does not does not call any methods until a link is actually activated, and it does not expose any information about its subviews. There is no way to do with current SDK, you should [file](http://bugreporter.apple.com/) a bug with Apple if you need this functionality.

Comment: And Apple will promptly ignore your bug request.